# Cycle through a resource until all the parameters are satisfied

Tags: python

I am trying to log a process; this process has 3 states, and they are sequential, so A->B->C; they can happen only in this sequence.

The only way that I have to follow this process is through a function, that return the current state of a specific type analyzed, that is passed to the function.The return data from a function (it is a list), which looks like this:

```
[typeX, date, time, process running]
compound, 12/12/14, 10:20, A
```

I need to be sure that a specific type, goes from A to B and then C. I am using this in a chemical analysis application, that parse results coming from a machine. I can't do nothing beside use the API that the machine supply; and this function is one of them. You can run it any time you want; it will always return the info about a specific type.

my approach:

```
running = True
while running:
    return_value = myfunction(type)  
    if A in return_value[3]:
        valueA = True
        print "found A"
    if B in return_value[3]:
        valueB = True
        print "found B"
    if C in return_value[3]:
        valueC = True
        print "found C"    
    if valueA and valueB and ValueC:
        running  = False
        print "Done"
```

This works, but it looks not really elegant IMO; since every time I run the function, it will verify again all the if conditions, even if I already found one or 2 of them. Not a big concern for my example, but I have to run this on a process that deal with thousands of entry, so performances may be an issue in the long run. Also if I call the function and it return the same value, I  get printed the value over and over:

```
found A
found A
[value change]
found B
found B
found B
[value change]
found C
Done
```

Pretty sure that there is a better way; if I put a sleep in the while loop, I may loose state B, and get only A and C, if I do it too often, I will get print on screen that goes on forever, printing the same string, since the value didn't change.

The final result should be one print per type; in this way I don't get a long output. What would be a good pythonic way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few ideas come to mind.

Simplest approach to the "one print per type" would be just to add a check for each value in the `if` statement (provided you have them set to `False` somewhere)

`if A in return_value[3] and not valueA:`

You could simplify it a bit like this:

```
a_found = b_found = c_found = False

while not (a_found and b_found and c_found):
    return_value = myfunction(type)
    if A in return_value[3] and not a_found:
        a_found = True
        print("found A")

    [...]

print("Done")
```

Comment: I see; so you set the initial while loop as if all of them are not true. Each time that a value is found, it will print out the message, and change the variable to true; and the second time that it run, if the value is the same, it will skip it because a_found is true now. And this reduce the amount of code that has to be processed in the while loop, which should increase performances. Thanks!